# What was Captain Britain's reaction to Psylocke's new body?

Tags: marvel, x-men

Was there ever a comic or a storyline that showed their reunion after Betsy Braddock's mind was placed in Kwannon's body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for *"Ghost of Braddock Manor"* printed in [Excalibur #55](http://uncannyxmen.net/comics/issue/excalibur-1st-series-55) from October 1992.

[image]

Prior to 1991 the world believed the [Uncanny X-Men](http://marvel.wikia.com/Uncanny_X-Men_Vol_1?file=Uncanny_X-Men_Vol_1_227.jpg) to be dead, having [died on live TV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_of_the_Mutants#Uncanny_X-Men) trying to save the world.  This included Besty Braddock (AKA [Psylocke](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/images/users/uploads/27306/PSYLOCKE_costume_2_050811.jpg)), in her original body... actually though they were all living in Australia.  After being attacked by [The Reavers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reavers_(comics)),  [Psylocke](http://goodcomics.comicbookresources.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/psylocke-bigcostume4.jpg) leads the [X-Men](http://bigotherbigother.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/siege-perilous.jpg?w=660) through the [Siege Perilous](http://marvel.wikia.com/Siege_Perilous) and is later found in a new body.

The world eventually discovers the [X-Men](http://uncannyxmen.net/glossary/groups/x-men) are alive, after the events in [Genosha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genosha) know as [X-Tinction Agenda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Tinction_Agenda). While the X teams are crossing-over in [X-Tinction Agenda](http://veryfinenearmint.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/xwantedposter.jpg) Brian Braddock (AKA [Captain Britain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Britain)) & [Excalibur](http://marvel.wikia.com/Excalibur_%28Earth-616%29) were busy with adventures of their own.

Finally in issue 55 of [Excalibur](http://uncannyxmen.net/glossary/groups/excalibur) we see Betsy visit her brother at Braddock Manor and catch up... though in true comic book hero fashion they barely mention her transformation.

Comment: That answers my question, thank you. Of course, that issue's not in Marvel Unlimited yet. I'll read it someday!

Comment: You're very welcome!